# Cloud9 - Workspace that update alone

Tags: cloud9-ide

Sometimes, I see that my workspace are updated alone.

Cloud9 says: "Updated X time ago", but I have no more information.
It may be an error of Cloud9? This happens to me in workspace that I'm alone and I've already changed the password.

Does this happen to anyone else?

**UPDATE:** 
Response from Cloud9.

"Hi Sebastian,

Thanks for getting in touch about this issue. I looked into your issue, and it turns out to be our automated backups. We actually take periodic backups of both active and inactive workspaces, and this updates the "updated" time stamp. I'll talk to the teams about not updating the time stamp when backups are performed. This should be very helpful to avoid any future concerns users may have :)"

Comment: Hi, do you mean that your 'updated x hours ago' line gets updated even without your accessing the workspace itself? Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Yes, exactly. My workspace has updated alone without my access. I don't know why

Comment: This should never happen. Please write to support@c9.io with your cloud9 username, workspace and some screenshots.